# Extract images/texts from PDF using Perl

Tags: perl, pdf, perl-module

I am trying to extract texts/images/tables from a PDF file using Perl.

I tried using [`CAM::PDF`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF) which is not extracting in text but as some other format.

Is there a method to extract texts/images/tables from a PDF using Perl modules?

Comment: Is there an example PDF file on line that you can link to?

Comment: `pdftohtml` from Poppler. No need to lose your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

@priya..i tried this module which is working fine for PDF text extraction..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::OCR::Thorough;


my $filename = "pdf.pdf";

my $pdf = PDF::OCR::Thorough->new($filename);
my $text = $pdf->get_text();
print "$text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.60/lib/CAM/PDF.pm). It has some methods that will help you extract images or other elements:

```
$doc->getProperty($pagenum, $propertyname)
Each PDF page contains a list of resources that it uses (images, fonts, etc). getPropertyNames() returns an array of the names of those resources. getProperty() returns a node representing a named property (most likely a reference node).
```

Comment: i used CAM::PDF -J Atwal . But i am not getting the proper output in stdout. the output is something like:

 ↓ ◄ ↑ ◄ § ◄ U ↨ ← ▬ § §
 0 X ♥ 6 \ V W H P ♥ , 3
 ¶ ‼ ◄ ¶ § ◄ § ‼ ∟ ◄ § ▬ →
 0 X ♥ 6 \ V W H P ♥ 6 H U L D O ♥ ♠
 ‼ § ‼ § ► ¶ ↑ ¶ ‼ ► ‼ ‼ ‼ ‼ ► ‼ ‼ ▬ '
 0 X ♥ 6 \ V W H P ♥ 8 V H U
 D G P L Q

 ' H Q L D O ► R I ► 6 H U Y L F H ♥ ♂ ' R 6 ♀ ♥ 5 H V X O

 $ Y D L O D E L O L W \
 § ‼ ♥ P L Q X W H V ♥ ¶ ♥ V H F R Q G
 ¶ § ¶ ♥ P L O O L V H F R Q G V
 ¶
 5 H F R Y H U H G ♥ Z L W K L Q ♥ ¶ ♥ P L Q X W H
 ♥
 ( [ H F X W L Y H ♥ 6 X P P D U \ ♥ 5 H S R U W ↔ ♥
 $ 5 3 B ▬ ▬ ¶ ↑ B ' R 6

Comment: hope you are not trying to print images on stdout ;). Try saving the image content to a file and then open the file in an image explorer.

Comment: this is not image but text. even then it is printing like this.